# SQL greater or equal (>=) not returning correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run a mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE salary >= '50000';
```

It returns all the jobs which salaries are over 50000. However, there is two jobs, which have salaries of 8 and 9 and they are returned too. In fact, all jobs, which have salaries between 10 and 5 are returned. (For example, salaries which are 2 are not returned). It's pretty weird and I am not sure what is causing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, `salary` is stored as a string, but you want it ordered as a *number*.

If `salary` were a number, then the comparison would implicitly convert it.  Instead, be explicit:

```
WHERE salary + 0 >= 50000;
```

Then, fix the data.  Something like:

```
alter table jobs
    modify column salary decimal(20, 4);
```